# How to exit loop as soon as the user clicks ESC or 'q' key?

Tags: c++

Hell'o.
In my program, there is a method that refreshes console screen four times per second. My problem is to stop executing main loop as soon as the user clicks ESC or 'q' key, **without clicking ENTER after that**. The good reference (without sharing my code) is *game loop* and event handling. I code on Linux.

Comment: Tools like [Curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) handle this properly. You can also use OS-specific keyboard input functions.

Comment: Using standard C++ it's not possible. You have to resort to lower-lever (possibly OS level) systems (like Curses which was already mentioned).

Comment: In the simple case, input to your tty doesn't go to your program until the user hits enter (except in certain exceptional cases).  You need to escape from the simple case and put your tty in raw mode.  As previously mentions, curses (or ncurses) is a good approach.

Comment: yeah, I use ncurses in my program. I tried _while(getch() != 'q') { }_ but it stops executing, waits for the input, checks if it differ from 'q' and repeat (or no if I pressed 'q')...

Comment: This code does not work. It updates only if I pressed some key or exitting when I pressed ESC. I want my program to not stop everytime he hits wgetch, just update 4 times per second: `do{ draw-something; refresh; int key = wgetch(); if(key == 'q'){ stillWorking = false} }while(working);`

Comment: **I invoked cbreak() after initscr()** but still does not work